# Как развернуть docker контейнер в heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, непрерывная-интеграция, devops, clickhouse

Дано: рабочая машина на windows, на которой никак не хочет работать docker

Нужно: развернуть docker pull yandex/clickhouse-server (с докер хаба) прямо на heroku, без локальной установки докера

Какой командой это сделать в heroku CLI?

Comment: А вы читали [документацию](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)?

Comment: Конечно читал, а вы?

Comment: Мда... Тогда просто прямо укажу вот тут прочтите внимательно - [Pushing an existing image](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-an-existing-image)